# Facing issue regarding Selenium(with java) and Firefox connectivity

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

Error:  Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.

Before all scripts were working fine..but now every script has stopped working. 
I have updated Selenium version 3.0.1.(updated jar files), updated Firefox version 52.0.2 ...java version 8.

Please suggest what I am missing?

Comment: What's your geckodriver version?

Comment: If it is v0.15 then you'll have to use selenium 3.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with Geckodriver version `v0.15` , you have to use selenium `3.3.1`

You would need to provide firefox binary location. One way of doing it is by the below code -

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); //Location where Firefox is installed

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("moz:firefoxOptions", options);

FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

More info here - http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3-0-launch-firefox-with-geckodriver/

Answer (score 0):

For Selenium 2.x later versions need to maintain geckodriver for firefox browser and if you find same issue then add binary path to your driver instance and try again.

Reference:

[selenium 2.53.0 with firefox 46](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43135624/selenium-2-53-0-with-firefox-46/43136868#43136868)